# Does Stick have mental powers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil

In Episode 7 of Netflix' Daredevil, young Matt Murdoch meets Stick.

> When Matt asks Stick how he found him, Stick says 'The old biddy believes it was her idea', and the scene heavily implies that Stick has planted the idea that he could take Matt from the orphanage in the mind of the head nun.

Does Stick (in any media - comic/tv/movie) have some kind of mental powers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Stick](http://www.comicvine.com/stick/4005-11018/) within the Marvel-616 universe has telepathy and the ability to suck a person's life force out of them, but he is not shown to have mind control abilities. He is, however, known to be a tricky individual, so I could readily see him as having tricked the nun into thinking it was her idea.

> .... Stick also possessed certain mental abilites such as telepathy and the ability to mentally siphon a person's life-force from their body into his....

A related character, [Elektra](http://www.comicvine.com/elektra/4005-1802/), trained by Stick in the Marvel-616 universe, has been noted as having minor mind control abilities, so it is possible that she learned them from Stick, but I have found no evidence of having done so.

Comment: When I watched the new DD, I didn't realize Stick was the same character as in Elektra. Scott Glenn plays the part so differently (written differently as well) than what the movie played him. About the only similarities are they are both blind and they both kick butt.