# How did Stick find the young Matt Murdock?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil

Both Frank Miller's seminal *Man Without Fear* comic miniseries and the Netflix TV show adaptation touches on the critical training Matt received from Stick.

Though they both skim over the **how-they-even-met** part.

So is there a clear explanation or a flashback in the canon that reveals how Stick knew **just when and where** to find Matt?

Was there was some [Chaste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaste_(Marvel_Comics)) derived "*Chosen One*" type of prophecy that mystically led Stick to Matt? Or did young *learning-to-use-his-gifts* Matt do some amazing news-worthy feat that attracted the Chaste or Stick's attention?

**UPDATE:**

Added a few images to help connect the dots between the comics canon and the show as it relates to this question. This convinces me that something was known to the Chaste well before, though I just don't know how and when this happened.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related, not dupe: [Does Stick have mental powers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87602/5184)

Comment: Yes, that did explain how a blind man can whisk away a kid but how did the blind man even know when and where to look? :)

Comment: In the Netflix series, the people at the orphanage reached out to Stick (or one of stick's associates), as I recall. He didn't just show up out of the blue.

Comment: @CreationEdge: Could you expand on this as a possible answer? The implication here is that somebody in the orphanage knew of Matt's abilities and passed the message along to a network that reached out to Stick, correct?

Comment: Very well, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the 11:00 minute mark of Season 1 Episode 7 *Stick*, the scene is a flashback to when Stick and Matt Murdock first met.

It's at an orphanage run by nuns. It starts out with Matt writhing in pain on his bed. Then, it cuts to Stick walking alongside a nun. They speak:

> **Nun:** He's getting worse. When we first took him in, Matthew's problems seemed less severe. Now he's in *so* much pain. Doctor's, clergy, no one has any idea what's wrong with him. We heard about your work with special children and thought maybe you could help.
> **Stick:** Not for free.

So, it seems that Stick has a reputation for helping "special" children. Likely, this is due to his involvement with the Chaste and trying to find new recruits with special abilities.

Stick himself later hints at this being part of what he does, in a conversation with Matt. Again, this happens during a flashback, with the relevant dialogue starting around the 16:35 mark of the same episode:

> **Matt:** If I ask you a question, will you hit me?
> **Stick:** Depends on the question.
> **Matt:** How did you find me? How did you know?
> **Stick:** Old bitty at the orphanage thinks it's her idea.
> **Matt:** But it wasn't, was it?
> **Stick:** Maybe it's one of my gifts. Or you just got lucky.
> **Matt:** That's not an answer.

However, here, the implication is that the nun reaching out wasn't actually a factor in Stick finding Matt. This further pushes the idea that there is some mysticism or work of The Chaste going on here.

But, as young Matt so clearly told us, we don't actually get an answer.

This, obviously, only accounts for the Marvel Cinematic Universe. I can't provide an answer for the comic continuity.

Comment: Note to viewers: I transcribed the scene myself, with the help of closed captions for consistency. If you notice any errors, please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

Stick is a telepath like Professor X and can sense the spirit realm (like Dr Strange). He was monitoring both Matt and Elektra like Obi Wan and Luke Skywalker etc

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This answer would be a lot better though if you edited it to include evidence (such as video clips, gifs, quotes, and episode citations) of what you've stated here.